# EasyMock change class of a mock

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock

in my code I have an instance variable

```
protected IFigure primaryShape
```

and a setter that uses primaryShape

```
protected void setLineWidth(int width) {
    if (primaryShape instanceof Shape) {
        ((Shape) primaryShape).setLineWidth(width);
    }
}
```

Now I want to test this setter and in my testclass I have this mock:

```
@Mock(type = MockType.NICE, name= "primaryShapeMock", fieldName = "primaryShape")
private MyClassFigure primaryShapeMock;
```

and this testmethod

```
@Test
public void testSetLineWitdh(){
    objectUnderTest.setLineWidth(0);
}
```

This way I can only test the true branch of the if-case, but how can I test the false branch? Do I really need to create a new Testclass for that case or could I change the class of the mock to test it in the same testclass?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what are the alternatives of instanceof ? Becauce the method was automatic generated.